# Как узнать что хранится в определенном участке оперативки

Tags: java, память, ram

Возможно ли при помощи софта узнать какая информация хранится в определенном участке оперативной памяти?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможно, но вы только узнаете, что где то по адресу Х хранится байт У - вам это может поможет, а может и не поможет, в зависимости от вашей задачи.

Comment: пример приложения, которое скнирует помять процессов - чит прога ArtMoney.